# What is a SMAPI context header?

Tags: sonos

The customsd.htm page now has this option:
"Include SMAPI context headers with all requests"
What does this mean? What is a smapi context header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context header is a new feature to allow Sonos to share additional contextual information with our partners.  Currently this design is still evolving and hence the WSDL and documentation has not been published.

This adds an additional SOAP header to requests which will in the future provide additional information including but limited to TimeZone.  Given that the format will change in a way that could break implementations we are not yet ready to publish the format of the header.  However if you turn the feature on you should be able to see what it adds to requests.

Comment: Keith, now that Sonos 6.0 has been released publically, any chance of updating the SMAPI documentation to include Context? Plus anything else that was added in 6.0.

Comment: The documentation update is planned and should be available soon.